# Docker:issue faced while running two web apps inside docker

Tags: docker

I am running two web apps inside docker. For this i have two physical folder for each app. Then i am creating two images for this. At same time i am exposing port 80 for both two apps. When i am trying to map with these port to 80 again then for running 2nd app it is saying port is already bind. Could anyone tell how to proceed.

I am running both apps in nginx web server.

I am trying to understand nginx reverse proxy concept. This is the one through which both two apps able to listen the same port. Can someone make it a little bit clear what & all changes i need to do.

Answer (score 1):

You expose the port 80, but you don't have to map it to the host port.

Only your nginx starts on port 80.

Then its nginx config will proxy-pass back to the two running container (one for each app), each exposing their port 80 (but not mapped on the host)

First, you link those two containers on the nginx when you run nginx:

```
docker run -it -d --name nginx.cont -p 80:80 \
 --link app1.cont:nginx.app1.cont \
 --link app2.cont:nginx.app2.cont \
 nginx
```

Then, you make sure your nginx config is to reference those two apps:

```
    location /app1/ {
      proxy_pass https://nginx.app1.cont:80/;
    }
    location /app2/ {
      proxy_pass https://nginx.app2.cont:80/;
    }
```

The neat parts are:

- you always reverse proxy back to port 80: each containers for each apps act as their own server, each one using *their* port 80 (no conflict on the host, as you don't reference back the host, you reference back directly the app containers)
- you always use a fixed name (here "`nginx.app1.cont`" or "`nginx.app2.cont`") because that name is, at runtime, when you run nginx, mapped to the actual name of the app containers (that you have started first).

Comment: Hay Vonc , I don't understand few things. Could u please elaborate a little bit more.
--name nginx.cont -------> Here what is nginx.cont?
app1.cont:nginx.app1.cont--------> Here i don't understand what is app1.cont because i am running apps like : http:localhost:80

Do i need to refer these names of apps in /etc/hosts?

Comment: @HariKrishna it is the name you want to give to your nginx container when you run it. I like to end that name by ".cont", as a naming convention, to help me remember that it is a container.

Comment: @HariKrishna app1.cont and app2.cont would be the name of the two containers (one per app) that you have launched previously, before launching the nginx one.

Comment: Thanks VonC i got your point. But what is app1 in location while making some changes in .conf file. Is it the path of the .html file or something else?

Comment: @HariKrishna I assume app1 is running in its own container; the reverse proxy of nginx will redirect any http://nginx.url/an/app1/path to http://app1.url/an/app1/path: the part behind the http://xxx/ will be passed along to the actual app1 server.

Comment: @HariKrishna Seriously? You had selected the right answer!

Comment: It was a mistake that i clicked. I am getting some other issues over it. Once it resolved i will select the right answer.